# Typing inside TextView causes entire layout/screen to "vibrate"

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, material-design, android-textinputedittext

I have the following layout:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

  
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/side_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/layout_margin_large"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/side_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/layout_margin_default">

      
            <!-- Some oother stuff....-->
            
            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layout_margin_default"
                android:text="@string/optional_data" />

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/brand"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layout_margin_default"
                app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/baseline_store_24">
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="text" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/model"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layout_margin_default"
                app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/baseline_directions_car_24">
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="text" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/build_year"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layout_margin_default"
                app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/baseline_event_24">
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="date" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/license_plate"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layout_margin_default"
                app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/baseline_pin_24">
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="text" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/vin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layout_margin_default"
                app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/baseline_shield_car_24">
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="text" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/note"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layout_margin_default"
                app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/baseline_notes_24">
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:minLines="3"
                />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Which looks like this:
https://jmp.sh/v/YgokjVB6XvyHAQqvoFlK

As you can see from the video, the issue I'm having is that when typing in the last `TextInputEditText`, my entire layout/screen starts to vibrate/shake, at least when I am in the first two line, when typing in my `minLine` (3) the vibration/shake stop or when I move the keyboard a little bit above the bottom line.

Removing the `minLine` attribute would solve the problem, however I want to set a minimum amount of lines/minimum height and the optimal way to do this is by using the `minLine` attribute.

I'm wondering what the issue might be? Is it maybe cause I don't have enough margin to the navigation bar?